# Getting class of return generic type possible?

Tags: java, generics

I want to know the class of a generic return type of a method, something like this:

```
    <T> T getEntry() { System.out.println(T.class) }
```

The problem is, this is not a generic class, this is just a generic method, so I can't extract the generic type from the class. What I want to achieve is knowing what concrete type the caller wants without requiring the class, like:

```
<T> T getEntry(Class<?> clazz);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Nope. Generics are erased at runtime.

Comment: What the heck! You answered seconds after I published! Are you some kind of bot?

Comment: Actually, 1 minute and 9 seconds. Time enough :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if Kylar is right I've to resort to:

```
<T> T getEntry(String name, Class<T> clazz)
```

I wanted to avoid the extra argument :(

Comment: That however depends on what you need the `Class<T>` for. If it's e.g. to create a `newInstance()`, then it's indeed mandatory. But if it's just to cast the `return` value, then you can also just do `return (T) value;` instead of `return clazz.cast(value);` and live with the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` ;)

Comment: I need to create an instance of an object with Spring SpEL, something like:

parser.parseExpression(expr).getValue(clazz.getName());